# How to use SQL SELECT as field name

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use select as column name to store the get total member, But I didn't succeed to get the solution for the right sql statement to use.
Here is my database table structure and sql that I have used.

Sql

```
    SELECT 
        name, 
        SELECT
               (
                   (COALESCE(SUM(adult),0) + COALESCE(SUM(elders),0))
                ) as total 
    FROM members 
        LEFT JOIN company 
        ON company.companyId = members.companyId
    GROUP BY company.companyId
```

My tables

```
            company table
    +----------------------+
    | companyId |  Name    |
    +-----------+----------+
    |  1        | Company1 |
    |  2        | Company2 |
    +-----------+----------+

                       members table
    +--------------------------------------------+
    |  id  | companyId | gender | adult | elders |
    +------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+
    |   1  |     1     |  male  |  200  |   700  |                                      
    |   1  |     1     | female |  300  |    50  |                                      
    |   1  |     2     |  male  |  100  |   500  |                                      
    |   1  |     2     | female |  900  |   800  |                                      
    +------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+

                    expected Results table
    +-------------------------------------------------+
    | companyId |  Name    | adult | elders | Total   |
    +-----------+----------+-------+--------+---------+
    |  1        | Company1 | 500   |  750   |  1250   |
    |  1        | Company2 | 1000  |  1300  |  2300   |
    +-----------+----------+-------+--------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` starting on `members` is not appropriate, unless members could lack a company.  I'll just use a regular `JOIN`.

Then you want aggregation with arithmetic:

```
SELECT c.companyId, c.name,
       SUM(m.adults + m.elders) as total,
       SUM(m.adults) as adults, SUM(m.elders) as elders
FROM members m JOIN 
     company c
     ON c.companyId = m.companyId
GROUP BY c.companyId, c.name;
```

You would use a `LEFT JOIN` if one of the following were true and you wanted to avoid filtering rows out:

- Some members do not have a valid `companyId`.
- Some companies have no rows in `members`.

Comment: Thank you very mush, It's working fine as I expected! Thank you.